# Hbase java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/MasterNotRunningException

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm running my hbase program using

> java -classpath  run.jar com.mycompany.app.HBaseImporter test2
>   /home/rahulko/Downloads/my-app/xaa

I have specified the HADOOP_CLASSPATH in hadoop.env.sh like this

```
 for f in $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar; do
 if [ "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" ]; then
 export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$f
 else
 export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$f
 fi
 done


export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$HBASE_HOME/lib/hbase-client-0.98.18-hadoop2.jar:\
$HBASE_HOME/lib/hbase-common-0.98.18-hadoop2.jar:\
$HBASE_HOME/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:\
$HBASE_HOME/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:\
$HBASE_HOME/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:\
$HBASE_HOME/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.18-hadoop2.jar"
```

I have also specified in bashrc

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hbase1/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*
```

But I'm still getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/MasterNotRunningException

But when I run from eclipse the program runs successfully

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using

> java -cp "run.jar:/usr/local/hbase1/lib/*"
>   com.mycompany.app.HBaseImporter test2
>   /home/rahulko/Downloads/my-app/xaa

Answer (score 0):

mkdir like libs and put you dependents jar into this

and run this command:

java -Djava.ext.dirs=/xxx/xxx/libs -jar /xxx/xxx/you program jar

that can auto use the dependents jar